# N prime numbers in java

Tags: java

So I've written this code in java which should output numbers on the screen from 1 to n(given by the user) and it should write "-prime" near the ones that are prime.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class primeMass {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int i,j;
        System.out.print("Dati n: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for(j=2;j<=n/2;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                    System.out.println(i);
                else System.out.println(i +"-prime");

    }}

}
```

If I input 6 for example i get :

```
Dati n: 6
1-prime
1-prime
2
2-prime
3-prime
3
4
4-prime
5-prime
5-prime
6
6
```

I'm new to this, and i'm really struggling with my algorithmic, could you tell me how should i change my program so it outputs correct values, and explain to me what i did wrong ? Thank you

UPDATE:

I've done it, thank you everyone for helping me out : this is the outcome:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class primeMass {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int i,j;
    boolean gasit = false;
    System.out.print("Dati n: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        gasit=false;
        for(j=2;j*j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0) gasit=true;}
        if(!gasit) {System.out.println(i+"-prime");}
        else {
            System.out.println(i);}

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `j <= i/2` or `j <= sqrt(i)` instead.

Comment: Step 1: proper formatting. Step 2: *debug* your code, set a breakpoint and step through the code statement by statement so that _you_ get an understanding of why the program behaves the way it does and then you can change it.

Comment: i've learned to debugg today , but i still didn't understand why it would go back again in the loop after printing the first i (for example)

Comment: "*but i still didn't understand why it would go back again in the loop after printing the first `i`*" why do you think loop should stop iterating? Can you explain based on what you are expecting such behavior? Also please use your editor to indent your code properly (most IDEs have such option to format/indent code according to standards/settings so it would be easier to read for people which are used to it - not to mention indentation helps us see the scope of code blocks).

Comment: BTW if you have solution don't place it in question section, but post it as an answer (you should see form section for answers at the bottom). When you post the answer use [edit] option and remove it from question section.

Answer (score 1):

You print something on every iteration of the inner loop.

Instead, you should print something *after* all iterations have completed, e.g.

```
boolean found = false;
for(j=2;j<=n/2;j++) {
  if(i%j==0) found = true;
}
if (!found) {
  System.out.println(i + "-prime");
} else {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be going up to `n/2`: you perhaps mean `i/2` (a number doesn't have any factors greater than itself); but you can make it even tighter, since you don't have to check for factors greater than `sqrt(i)`. Or, stated another way, that `j * j <= i`.

So you can make your loop declaration:

```
for(j=2; j*j<=i; j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second loop goes until `n/2`, it should go until `i/2` to check if `i` is prime. A more optimzed version of the primality check algorithm goes until `sqrt(i)`, as suggested in comments.

The next issue is that you are concluding, in a false way, that if in the first case `if(i%j==0)` you say not prime, otherwise you say it is prime, which is not true necessairly. You should iterate the whole interval of values between `[2:i/2]` to conclude that `i` is prime.